# Zend Framework group by case

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I having trouble using zend framework mysql groupby query. What I am trying to achieve is this query

```
SELECT * FROM `price_list` AS `pl` 
GROUP BY 
CASE WHEN `pl`.`sub_folder` IS NULL THEN 
`pl`.`id` 
ELSE 
`pl`.`sub_folder` 
END 
ORDER BY `pl`.`date_added` DESC
```

Here is what I tried in zend way

```
$sql = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);       
$sql->from(array('pl'=>$this->_name), array(''))
    ->columns($cols)
    ->group("case when pl.sub_folder is null then pl.id else pl.sub_folder end");
```

but that output this sql string with wrong quote on case condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `price_list_pdf` AS `pl` 
GROUP BY `CASE WHEN pl`.`sub_folder is null then 
pl`.`id 
ELSE
pl`.`sub_folder 
end` 
ORDER BY `pl`.`date_added` DESC
```

How do I clear this ` in the string? or is there any better way to do? Please help..

Comment: did you try to remove single quotes from group statements ??

Comment: yea I did, I was actually testing by adding those single quotes

Comment: Yes. I think your SQL is not proper. Try it removing single quotes, except for aliases

Comment: @Aditya yea I tried without single quote ' but this ` quote is still adding on CASE condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unescaped querys use `Expressions` like

```
$sql = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);       
$sql->from(array('pl'=>$this->_name), array(''))
        ->columns($cols)
        ->group(new Zend_Db_Expr("case when pl.sub_folder is null then pl.id else pl.sub_folder end"));
```

Comment: great it worked! I used "new Zend_Db_Expr" instead. May be "new Expression" is for version 2.0+

Comment: oh my fault, yeah i was thinking you use zf2 (don't saw any related zf1 structure)...sure for zf1 it's like you say ``Zend_Db_Expr`` - the basic procedure is the same